# How can i trigger a bootstrap modal at a specific height of the window scroll , for just Once?

Tags: jquery, scroll, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to show user a modal window when vertical scrollbar position is beyond a specified limit.

Here is my HTML code

```
      <div class="container">
          <h2>Modal Example</h2>
          <!-- Trigger the
      modal with a button -->
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <script>
      $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1000) {
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
          }
      });
      </script>
      <p>
          Cupidatat master cleanse carles small batch VHS. Brooklyn umami odio, post-ironic selvage hella farm-to-table. Brooklyn DIY cardigan cosby sweater marfa. 
          Gastropub bicycle rights in seitan non small batch. Placeat non street art umami, yr wolf sed skateboard cupidatat direct trade seitan put a bird on it occaecat 
          small batch. Hoodie marfa umami, enim scenester cred synth vero gastropub aliqua brunch mlkshk ut. Sed brunch pop-up irony quis. Etsy stumptown 3 wolf moon in 
          carles, vinyl chillwave. Beard sapiente nulla banh mi cosby sweater 8-bit craft beer, ethical art party portland tumblr godard quinoa occaecat et. Stumptown art 
          party ea bushwick. Cardigan DIY non cred ullamco duis. Id gastropub pop-up narwhal culpa fanny pack voluptate, street art gluten-free eiusmod quis aute lo-fi. 
          Nostrud ethical irure keffiyeh umami lomo. Twee swag nihil culpa odd future. > </p>
```

Comment: `Cupidatat master cleanse carles sma....` what is all this ?

Comment: just a dummy text , i want the pop-up to show at a certain height of the page thats why ..

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle @ jsfiddle.net of above so we can help easily and understand your problem better.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2kcmpym9/

Comment: @Err It is working on my local but, the pop-up is not showing up even once in js fiddle , please help

Comment: Check now, i have solved that modal problem. Check here : https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/2kcmpym9/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101253/discussion-between-err-hunter-and-azhar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an attribute to your modal, for example `displayed` and set a value which you can use as a flag for displayed once or not. And on scroll do check for attribute value. and change it after being displayed once.

So your html should be something like,

`<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" displayed="false">`

and your script tag invoking modal should be something like,

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if ($(document).scrollTop() > 3000 && $("#myModal").attr("displayed") === "false") {
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
         $("#myModal").attr("displayed", "true");
       }
     });
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/wLp7sszu/1/) demonstrating same.

Comment: Glad i helped. Just a side-not : above is not the best way but not a bad way too. GL.

Comment: That fiddle, at least on my screen, never reaches scrollTop() > 3000, stopping instead at 2686. Try lowering the threshold if this jsFiddle isn't working.